# stop the program if promise fails

Tags: node.js, promise

How can I stop my node server if a promise fails ?

```
myPromise.then(res => {})
   .catch(err => {
    throw "bad error"  // I want to stop the program like I in the synchronous senario. Not get unhandled promise exception
})
```

Comment: `process.exit(1)`  If you want do be more graceful, post how you are creating your server.  You will need to attach `on("error")` listeners to your server and stop from there.

Answer (score 1):

Call the `exit()` function on the global `process` object with a non-zero exit code.

```
myPromise
  .then((res) => {})
  .catch((err) => process.exit(1));
```

Read more here:
https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code